# Group Inbound & Outbound emails by address and show in threaded view style in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am not a programmer, Our company currently uses ACT CRM integrated with Outlook. Since ACT CRM and Outlook are not cloud based, we are having a CRM built in ZEND Framework. Our issue is tracking email correspondence with our clients. Right now ACT captures via Outlook both inbound and outbound emails and attaches them to the contact record. Our Zend CRM only can capture outbound messages initiated from the program and attached them to the contact record. We want inbound messages to be attached, by comparing or recognizing the inbound email address and then attaching it to the matching contact. Is this possible, our developer does not know.

Comment: We are wishing to record all inbound and outbound email correspondence with each client in our Zend CRM. Right now we can capture outbound emails per and have them displayed in clients contact record window. But we can{t get their replies.